Django static fill unable connect
enter image description here
I'm unable to connect my static file to myproject this is my static file registerd in settingsSTATIC_URL = 'static/' after that in template html i added load static and static before adding css file
<!-- Required meta tags -->
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'website/css/style.css' %}">

